How measure fan signal that not seems to the ground isolated?
I have voltronic inverter 3k fan  stops with code 01 its mean fan need a replacement
old fan in  pic-01 its use us62 ic  so i order new fan pic-02 and its not working
first reason the cables reversed gnd and signal and pulse are normally measured by connecting the signal and gnd on old fan but on the new one it's not
it can measure only by  conneст  signal and vcc
also signal is reversed  its use  LB11967V driver on RD pin
my question how can to reverse the signal and measure it with signal and gnd

pic-01 old fan

pic-02 new fan

pic-03 new fan board

it is unclear what you are saying ... please divide the pile of words into sentences

Sounds like your fan has an open collector output and you need a pull-up resistor to Vcc.
